# RSA code in matlab

Tags: matlab, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I want to encrypt a message such as **'HELO1234** and then decrypt to get the original one.I have written RSA code in matlab which is not working correctly.

> PARAMETER CALCULATION

```
temp=1;
range=1:10;
k=isprime(range)
prime_mat=range(find(k))
p=randsample(prime_mat,1);
q=randsample(prime_mat,1);
if(p~=q)
n=p*q;
phi_n=(p-1)*(q-1);
u=1:phi_n -1;
end
while temp
 enckey=randsample(u,1);
  deckey=randsample(u,1);
  if(enckey~=deckey)
  if(gcd(enckey,phi_n)~=1 ...
     && gcd(deckey,phi_n)~=1 ...
   &&gcd(enckey*deckey,phi_n)~=1)
    temp=1;
 else 
 temp=0;
  end
  end
end
```

> ENCRYPTION PROCESS

```
 char t= 'hello123';
      t=uint8(t);
        len=length(t)
         pow=[];
         cipher_text=[];
           for i=1:len                                   
               pow=[pow;t(i).^(enckey)];  %each element of the pt matrix(plain text) is raised    to the power of encryption key(enc_key) and stored in pow matrix(power matrix)

    cipher_text=[cipher_text;mod(pow(i),n)];% cipher text is calculate
```

d

> OUTPUT OF encryption process

k =

```
 0     1     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     0
```

prime_mat =

```
 2     3     5     7
```

p =

```
 7
```

q =

```
 2
```

n =

```
14
```

enckey =

```
 5
```

deckey =

```
 1
```

phi_n =

```
 6
```

len =

```
28
```

cipher_text =

```
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
```

> DECRYPTION PROCESS

```
plain_text=[];
pow1=[];
len1=length(cipher_text);
for i=1:len
    pow1=[pow1;cipher_text(i).^(deckey)]
    plain_text=[plain_text;mod(pow1(i),n)]
```

uint8(plain_text);

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete. And what do you mean by "not working correctly"?

Comment: Try to use existing one http://www.hackchina.com/en/cont/49303

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: @ phonon please see the output after encryption process

Comment: @ cheery the code is in java.I want that code to run in matlab without thehelp of java ,if possible.

Comment: Is this for use in production code, or as an exercise in learning how the math behind the cryptography works?

Comment: @ Andrew yeah I am doing a project which requires implementation in real scenario

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't bother implementing it yourself. Writing crypto is hard and bugs have security consequences. Use a well-known library from a trusted vendor.

In Matlab, you can call down to the standard Java cryptography classes included with the JVM bundled with Matlab. The Matlab code will look something like this.

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;

plaintext = 'foobar';

cipher = Cipher.getInstance('RSA');
keygen = java.security.KeyPairGenerator.getInstance('RSA');
keyPair = keygen.genKeyPair();
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPrivate());

plaintextUnicodeVals = uint16(plaintext);
plaintextBytes = typecast(plaintextUnicodeVals, 'int8');
ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(plaintextBytes)'  %'

% And back out
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPublic());
decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
decryptedText = char(typecast(decryptedBytes, 'uint16'))'
```